# Loop unrolling and SSE -- clang vs gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, clang, simd

*Disclaimer: full code can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GC9vyT).*

## 16 byte alignment

Given a fairly simple type to support proper SSE alignment

```
struct alignas(16) simd_pack
{
    std::int32_t data[4];
};
```

and a function that adds two arrays together

```
void add_packed(simd_pack* lhs_and_result, simd_pack* rhs, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            lhs_and_result[i].data[j] += rhs[i].data[j];
}
```

compile the code with clang and gcc using `-O3`.

Clang produces the following assembly:

```
add_packed(simd_pack*, simd_pack*, unsigned long):          # @add_packed(simd_pack*, simd_pack*, unsigned long)
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .LBB0_3
        mov     eax, 12
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 12]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 12], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 8]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 8], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 4]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 4], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax], ecx
        add     rax, 16
        add     rdx, -1
        jne     .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
        ret
```

I'm not very literate in assembly but to me it looks like clang is simply unrolling the inner for loop. If we take a look at gcc we get:

```
add_packed(simd_pack*, simd_pack*, unsigned long):
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L1
        sal     rdx, 4
        xor     eax, eax
.L3:
        movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
        paddd   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L3
.L1:
        ret
```

which is what I expect.

## 64 byte alignment

The difference gets even bigger (obviously) if we go to 64 byte alignment (which usually is a cache line if I'm not mistaken)

```
struct alignas(64) cache_line
{
    std::int32_t data[16];
};

void add_cache_line(cache_line* lhs_and_result, cache_line* rhs, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            lhs_and_result[i].data[j] += rhs[i].data[j];
}
```

Clang keeps simply unrolling:

```
add_cache_line(cache_line*, cache_line*, unsigned long):    # @add_cache_line(cache_line*, cache_line*, unsigned long)
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .LBB1_3
        mov     eax, 60
.LBB1_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 60]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 60], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 56]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 56], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 52]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 52], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 48]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 48], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 44]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 44], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 40]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 40], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 36]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 36], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 32]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 32], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 28]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 28], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 24]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 24], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 20]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 20], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 16]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 16], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 12]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 12], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 8]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 8], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax - 4]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax - 4], ecx
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi + rax]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + rax], ecx
        add     rax, 64
        add     rdx, -1
        jne     .LBB1_2
.LBB1_3:
        ret
```

while gcc uses SSE and also unrolls that:

```
add_cache_line(cache_line*, cache_line*, unsigned long):
        mov     rcx, rdx
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L9
        sal     rcx, 6
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rdx, rsi
        add     rcx, rdi
.L11:
        movdqa  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+16]
        movdqa  xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 64
        add     rdx, 64
        movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx-32]
        movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx-16]
        paddd   xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [rdx-64]
        paddd   xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rax-48]
        paddd   xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax-32]
        paddd   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax-16]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax-64], xmm3
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax-48], xmm2
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax-32], xmm1
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax-16], xmm0
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .L11
.L9:
        ret
```

## No alignment

It's getting interesting if we use plain 32 bit integer arrays with no alignment at all. We use the exact same compiler flags.

```
void add_unaligned(std::int32_t* lhs_and_result, std::int32_t* rhs, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        lhs_and_result[i] += rhs[i];
}
```

#### Clang

Clang's assembly exploaded a fair bit by adding some branches:

```
add_unaligned(int*, int*, unsigned long):                 # @add_unaligned(int*, int*, unsigned long)
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .LBB2_16
        cmp     rdx, 7
        jbe     .LBB2_2
        lea     rax, [rsi + 4*rdx]
        cmp     rax, rdi
        jbe     .LBB2_9
        lea     rax, [rdi + 4*rdx]
        cmp     rax, rsi
        jbe     .LBB2_9
.LBB2_2:
        xor     r10d, r10d
.LBB2_3:
        mov     r8, r10
        not     r8
        add     r8, rdx
        mov     rcx, rdx
        and     rcx, 3
        je      .LBB2_5
.LBB2_4:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsi + 4*r10]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + 4*r10], eax
        add     r10, 1
        add     rcx, -1
        jne     .LBB2_4
.LBB2_5:
        cmp     r8, 3
        jb      .LBB2_16
.LBB2_6:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsi + 4*r10]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + 4*r10], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsi + 4*r10 + 4]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + 4*r10 + 4], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsi + 4*r10 + 8]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + 4*r10 + 8], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsi + 4*r10 + 12]
        add     dword ptr [rdi + 4*r10 + 12], eax
        add     r10, 4
        cmp     rdx, r10
        jne     .LBB2_6
        jmp     .LBB2_16
.LBB2_9:
        mov     r10, rdx
        and     r10, -8
        lea     rax, [r10 - 8]
        mov     r9, rax
        shr     r9, 3
        add     r9, 1
        mov     r8d, r9d
        and     r8d, 1
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB2_10
        sub     r9, r8
        xor     ecx, ecx
.LBB2_12:                               # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movdqu  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi + 4*rcx]
        movdqu  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsi + 4*rcx + 16]
        movdqu  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx]
        paddd   xmm2, xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 16]
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movdqu  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 32]
        movdqu  xmm3, xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 48]
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx], xmm2
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 16], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi + 4*rcx + 32]
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movdqu  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsi + 4*rcx + 48]
        paddd   xmm1, xmm3
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 32], xmm0
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 48], xmm1
        add     rcx, 16
        add     r9, -2
        jne     .LBB2_12
        test    r8, r8
        je      .LBB2_15
.LBB2_14:
        movdqu  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi + 4*rcx]
        movdqu  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsi + 4*rcx + 16]
        movdqu  xmm2, xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx]
        paddd   xmm2, xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 16]
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx], xmm2
        movdqu  xmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rcx + 16], xmm0
.LBB2_15:
        cmp     r10, rdx
        jne     .LBB2_3
.LBB2_16:
        ret
.LBB2_10:
        xor     ecx, ecx
        test    r8, r8
        jne     .LBB2_14
        jmp     .LBB2_15
```

What is happening at `.LBB2_4` and `.LBB2_6`? It looks like it's unrolling a loop again but I'm not sure what happens there (mainly because of the registers used).

In `.LBB2_12` it even unrolls the SSE part. I think it's only unrolled two-fold though because it needs two SIMD registers to load each operand because they are unaligned now. `.LBB2_14` contains the SSE part without the unrolling.

How is the control flow here? I'm assuming it should be:

1. keep using the unrolled SSE part until the remaining data is too small to fill all the registers (`xmm0..3`)
2. switch to the single stage SSE part and do it once if we have enough data remaining to fill `xmm0` (4 integers in our case)
3. process the remaining data (3 operations at max, otherwise it would be SSE suitable again)

The order of the labels and the jump instructions are confusing, is that (approx.) what happens here?

#### GCC

Gcc's assembly is a bit easier to read:

```
add_unaligned(int*, int*, unsigned long):
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L16
        lea     rcx, [rsi+4]
        mov     rax, rdi
        sub     rax, rcx
        cmp     rax, 8
        jbe     .L22
        lea     rax, [rdx-1]
        cmp     rax, 2
        jbe     .L22
        mov     rcx, rdx
        xor     eax, eax
        shr     rcx, 2
        sal     rcx, 4
.L19:
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .L19
        mov     rax, rdx
        and     rax, -4
        test    dl, 3
        je      .L16
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4]
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4], ecx
        lea     rcx, [rax+1]
        cmp     rdx, rcx
        jbe     .L16
        add     rax, 2
        mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rsi+rcx*4]
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi+rcx*4], r8d
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jbe     .L16
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4]
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4], edx
        ret
.L22:
        xor     eax, eax
.L18:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4]
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4], ecx
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L18
.L16:
        ret
```

I assume the control flow is similar to clang

1. keep using the single stage SSE part until the remaining data is too small to fill `xmm0` and `xmm1`
2. process the remaining data (3 operations at max, otherwise it would be SSE suitable again)

It looks like exactly this is happening in `.L19` but what is `.L18` doing then?

## Summary

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/GC9vyT) is the full code, including assembly. My question are:

1. Why is clang unrolling the functions that use aligned data instead of using SSE or a combination of both (like gcc)?
2. What are `.LBB2_4` and `.LBB2_6` in clang's assembly doing?
3. Are my assumptions about the control flow of the function with the unaligned data correct?
4. What is `.L18` in gcc's assembly doing?

Comment: 4) that's code for the case where the length is less than 8 so the SSE path would not be worth it

Comment: clang *always* unrolls small loops, whether it auto-vectorizes or not.  GCC doesn't, unless it knows they're hot from PGO (`-fprofile-use`).  GCC spends huge amounts of code footprint on fully unrolling scalar intro/cleanup around tiny vectorized inner loops. :/  It looks like the possibility of overlap defeated clang for the struct case; try with `foo *__restrict p`

Comment: 2) those seem to be unrolled cases for the case when the regions overlap

Comment: @Jester why is there a threshold? And why 8? Do SSE instructions cost more compared to their simple counterparts?

Comment: @PeterCordes very interesting. I totally forgot about overlapping and yes, with `__restrict` clang also generates SSE instructions now. But how does this affect the packed types? I can see that it affects types that are smaller than a SIMD register (like `int`). However, if the size fits a SIMD register (like `simd_pack`) or even exceeds the size (like `cache_line`) overlapping cannot happen (within a SSE instruction).

Comment: @Timo: yes, that's a missed optimization; that kind of overlapping would be UB.  Other missed optimizations from  `simd_pack` include still only using 128-bit vectors with `-march=skylake` (not 256-bit AVX2), so I guess clang has a hard time flattening out those structs.

Comment: Clang actually gets worse, when trying to "help" by storing the sum in a temporary `cache_line` object before copying that back: https://godbolt.org/z/R2eRp7 -- probably worth reporting as a bug.